# Convert kotlin predicate to java

Tags: java, kotlin, predicate

How do you convert this Kotlin predicate to java:

```
List<SomeObjWithProp> lst = ...
Iterables.filter(lst) { obj -> obj?.property != null }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java has lambda expressions but not a safe-navigation operator, so you'll need to expand the null check explicitly:

```
Iterables.filter(lst, obj -> (obj != null && obj.getProperty() != null));
```